# Disable Zoom effect on Hover for Mobile devices in elevateZoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when you check the [elevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) on Mobile, the page scroll option does not work when we click on the image although we off the zoom option. which is a trouble.

We want to disable zoom option for **Mobile devices** or **responsive sizes**.

Is there any value or variable we can use to ONLY disable Zoom effect completely for mobile devices?

Can anyone suggest how to do this or if someone did it for their theme in past?

Answer (score 6):

ElevateZoom API you can get:

```js
var ezApi = $('#primaryImage').data('elevateZoom');
```

In order to enable/disable zoom you should use "changeState" method

```js
ezApi.changeState('enable'); // or disable
```

To detect change media query breakpoint you can use matchMedia

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
mq.addListener((b) => {
  if (b.matches) {
      // do something for screens > 768px, for example turn on zoom
      ezApi.changeState('enable');
  } else {
      // do something for screens < 768px, for example turn off zoom
      ezApi.changeState('disable');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try **Disable/Comment** Touch events in ***jquery.elevatezoom.js*** or ***jquery.elevateZoom version min (my version: 3.0.8)***:

```
//touch events

            /* self.$elem.bind('touchmove', function(e){    
                e.preventDefault();
                var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];  
                self.setPosition(touch);

            });  
            self.zoomContainer.bind('touchmove', function(e){ 
                if(self.options.zoomType == "inner") {
                    self.showHideWindow("show");

                }
                e.preventDefault();
                var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];  
                self.setPosition(touch); 

            });     
            self.zoomContainer.bind('touchend', function(e){ 
                self.showHideWindow("hide");
                if(self.options.showLens) {self.showHideLens("hide");}
                if(self.options.tint && self.options.zoomType != "inner") {self.showHideTint("hide");}
            });     

            self.$elem.bind('touchend', function(e){ 
                self.showHideWindow("hide");
                if(self.options.showLens) {self.showHideLens("hide");}
                if(self.options.tint && self.options.zoomType != "inner") {self.showHideTint("hide");}
            });     
            if(self.options.showLens) {
                self.zoomLens.bind('touchmove', function(e){ 

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];  
                    self.setPosition(touch); 
                }); */
```

Comment: me to guys, after countless hours of roaming trough the internet, coming to this answer helped me solve my issue with the Scroll not working on Mobile devices when your finger is touching the image.
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

try to

```
var image = $('#primaryImage');
var zoomConfig = {};
var zoomActive = false;

image.on('click', function(){

    zoomActive = !zoomActive;

    if(zoomActive)
    {
         image.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);//initialise zoom
    }
    else
    {
        $.removeData(image, 'elevateZoom');//remove zoom instance from image

        $('.zoomContainer').remove();// remove zoom container from DOM
    }
});
```

Other option

```
$('#primaryImage').click(function(){
   if($(window).width()>768){
        $(this).elevateZoom({
            zoomWindowPosition:1,
            zoomWindowOffetx: 5,
            zoomWindowWidth:$(this).width(), 
            zoomWindowHeight:$(this).height(),
        }); 
    }
    else{
        $.removeData($(this), 'elevateZoom');//remove zoom instance from image
        $('.zoomContainer').remove(); // remove zoom container from DOM
        return false;
    }
});
```

https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/issues/8

Answer (score 2):

Best Answer I've found and easiest from here: https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/issues/102#issuecomment-255942134

@media(max-width: $tablet-max) { /* The image that has zoom on it */ .product__img { pointer-events: none; } }

Answer (score 2):

In js plugin add this option

```
touchEnabled: false,
```

With this option in desktop PC image will be zoom and in mobile device, zoom will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just hide **.zoomContainer** using media queries?

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .zoomContainer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bad solution as the zoom is still triggered when you swipe anywhere over the image and prevents scrolling.

Comment: "This is a bad solution". This is working actually. I have access only via css and with this, on Android phone the zoom is disabled. So working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue so I edit my js file and put a if, else condition on it. This condition will act similar as CSS media query.

```
//JQUERY CODE

if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 500px)').matches) {
        jQuery.fn.elevateZoom.options = {
            zoomEnabled: true
        }
}else{
        jQuery.fn.elevateZoom.options = {
            zoomEnabled: false
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried everything and nothing works for you, try a CSS cover (it works perfect for me)

In your HTML:

```
<figure class="product-main-image">
    <div class="product-zoom-cover">&nbsp;</div>
    <img id="product-zoom" src="............">
</figure>
```

In your CSS:

```
.product-zoom-cover{
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .product-main-image{
        position: relative;
    }
    .product-zoom-cover{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 48;
    }
}
```

Success to all and good code!

Answer (score 0):

For those who still come from search engines to this topic, The best way to manage every option (like enable / disable on mobile) in different sizes is using plugin`s [documentation](https://igorlino.github.io/elevatezoom-plus/examples.htm)!
Here we go:

First you have to manage global options for elevatezoom:

```
jQuery('.mainproimg').ezPlus({
easing: true,
lensFadeIn: 200,
lensFadeOut: 200,
zoomWindowFadeIn: 200,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 200,
zoomWindowPosition: 11,
zoomWindowWidth: 400,
zoomWindowHeight: 400,
borderSize:1,
responsive: true
});
```

Then add the following code:

```
respond: [
            {
                range: '320-991',
                enabled: false,
                showLens: false
            }
        ]
```

So, the whole code would be:

```
jQuery('.mainproimg').ezPlus({
easing: true,
lensFadeIn: 200,
lensFadeOut: 200,
zoomWindowFadeIn: 200,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 200,
zoomWindowPosition: 11,
zoomWindowWidth: 400,
zoomWindowHeight: 402,
zoomWindowOffsetY: -8,
borderSize:1,
responsive: true,
enabled: true,
showLens: true,
respond: [
            {
                range: '320-991',
                enabled: false,
                showLens: false
            }
        ]
});
```

In this case, elevatezoom will be disabled on devices that has 320px to 991px width.
Of course you can add more ranges and manage plugin options for each breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

unbind touchmove from element

```
  $('#img-product-zoom').unbind('touchmove');
```

and then hide the container of zoom area

```
  $('.ZoomContainer').hide();
```

use this code to detect mobile phone

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
///here put your code
}
```